# spyOn service / component Angular2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to implement unit test with service. I'd like some clarification on why this isn't working.

setUp for my spec class.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(testComp);
    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);
});

 it('mockService', () => {
    spyOn(service, "testFuncCall");
    let buttonClick = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.testFuncCall'));
    buttonClick.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(service.testFuncCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

So the above runs fine and if I make the button click - click on a different button it will fail. 
What I was trying to do was

```
 it('mockService', () => {
    spyOn(service, "testFuncCall");
    spyOn(component, "testFuncCall");
    let buttonClick = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.testFuncCall'));
    buttonClick.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(component.testFuncCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(service.testFuncCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

This throws an error saying Expected spy testFuncCall to have been called. Just wondering why this happens. The component has a method called testFuncCall that gets initiated the button click. That method calls the Service which has a method with the same name testFuncCall.

If I have separate it, one for testing if the `component.testFuncCall` has been called and another for if the `service.testFuncCall` has been called, it seems fine. But combining those into one throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you spy on a method, you basically replace it with a method that doesn't do anything (other than recording the calls that are made to be able to verify them later). So, the fake component function doesn't do anything anymore, and thus doesn't call the service anymore.

You can make it do what it actually does by using

```
spyOn(component, "testFuncCall").and.callThrough();
```

See [the documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.8/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E)

Comment: Ahh okay, makes sense. Thanks.